# Find which Youtube video is a referral in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, referrer, youtube

I have many new visitors today coming thanks to a Youtube video. When I choose *Acquisition > All traffic > Referrals*, I see `Youtube`, and when clicking on it, here is what I see:

```
Referral path     Sessions

1. /              170
2. /mobile         20
```

When clicking on `/` or `/mobile` I unfortunately don't get the URL of the video.

**How to find which Youtube video is a referral to my website in Google Analytics?** (it's probably a video from someone that I don't know, so I cannot ask them to put a specific link with ?utm_campaign=...)

Comment: It sounds like people are watching the video in the playlist on the youtube home page.   If that is the case, I'm not sure if there is anything you can do.   I'd expect at least some people to view it from its permalink on youtube.  You should be able to see referrals for those.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to your source/medium report a second dimension "Ad Content" - what do you see?

If this will not help, so there should be accesses from YT homepage, as Stephen Ostermiller pointed out in his comment.

Comment: I see: `(not set)`